# Spherical Geometry library for Java/Python

Tags: java, python

Is there a good Spherical Geometry library for Java/Python? I'm looking for something similar to this http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/01/little-help-with-spherical-geometry.html. I need to be able to perform distance, heading, area calculations; would be nice if I can also do intersection and union of areas.

Comment: Perhaps using a database with GIS support, like MySQL or PostgreSQL, would help?

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth checking out the [3D Spherical Geometry Kernel](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Circular_kernel_3/Chapter_main.html) in [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) even though the code is written in C++. Writing robust geometric code can be tricky, but perhaps you could wrap a small number of appropriate functions using something like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)?